# Trouble enabling log4net in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, log4net

I need help in configuring log4net and Fluent NHibernate. It seems log4net is starting, but I'm not getting any information from NHibernate/Fluent NHibernate. I want this information to debug faulty mapping.

Configuration in App.config

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
    <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
<logger name="NHibernate"
    additivity="false">
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Here's how I launch log4net and configuration.

```
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        FluentConfiguration cfg = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ShowSql().InMemory())
            .Diagnostics(x => x.Enable());
        DbCtx.Source = new SessionSource(cfg.BuildConfiguration()
                                                .Properties, new PSModel());
```

The exception I'm getting is in the last line on cfg.BuildConfiguration(). I don't get any entries in log on how mapping went, though.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to see the messages in the output window in visual studio you should use the following instead:

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender" >
```

Also to see the log messages you may want to throw everything NHibernate spits out into your LogFileAppender as well:

```
<logger name="NHibernate"
    additivity="false">
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem laid in the fact that exception occured in Fluent NHibernate therefore logging for NHibernate wasn't able to kick in.